# Should I rename my question after it is answered because I didn't fully understand my problem?

Tags: discussion

One of the problems I've encountered on this site is the inability to find the answer to my questions through research. That being my case...

If I asked the question: "What is syntactically wrong with this code?"

And I received a working answer that indicates it's not a problem with syntax, but some other variable.

(If it is appropriate in the first place) When would it be appropriate for me to change a question title so that it's optimized for user research?

Comment: Edit your title if you think you have a better title after you found out what the problem is. (At best try to use a title which other SO visitors would search for if they have the same problem)

Comment: That's a pretty useless title to see even before your question is answered.  Your title should be indicating *something* about what's going on even before you've found a solution.

Comment: I completely understand. Though, I only used that question as a general example to explain my point. @Servy

Comment: It's never too early or too late to edit your questions or your answers to improve them.

Comment: +1 because I have always wondered this myself. It's very common to ask a question saying 'why is this problem happening' only for someone else to realize 'it's not that, but [this other] problem.'

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes. Yes, you should. Now would be a good time.

A misleading title will keep on misleading people for all eternity. Change it to a title that is representative of the specific problem described in the question.

For guidance, refer to the help center page, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), where you will find a section on writing good titles.

"What is wrong with my code" does not constitute a good title. It could literally apply to [millions of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/10m) on this site, none of which may have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: What would be your suggested rename?

Comment: Y'know, that would really depend on what the question is!

Comment: You said in your answer, "now would be a good time", so I assumed you meant this instance. My apologies.

Answer (score 16):

Yes you should always make efforts to make **contributions** that make the content better regardless.

Answer (score 9):

Rephrasing your question to make it more searchable, useful and understandable is great, as long as you're not changing the gist of what you're asking.

What you should **not** do is to edit the question **based on** the answers (which sort of seems to be the case here). Consider other people having the same question - they will not know the answer, thus they will probably not be able to find the modified question.

As others pointed out "What's wrong" is not a good title. If you construct [a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which you should, always), you should generally be able to come up with a more appropriate title such as "Why doesn't foo work?" or "How do I do bar?" or "Why am I getting error message blah?".

Answer (score 3):

Usually you should have a title that reflects the problem that you are trying to solve. So yes, edit it.

The only exception is when your question is a duplicate. That way, other people with the same misconceptions will use the same terms that you used in the title to search, and your question will lead them to the right answer.